# Sufficient assumptions to obtain boundedness of integral

Tags: lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

we have $$\displaystyle\int_{E\times(0,T)}f(x,\tau)^{p-1}\partial_\tau g(x,\tau)\,dx\,d\tau$$

with $f\in C(0,T;L^p(E))$ for some domain $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $p>1$ and $g\in W^{1,p}(0,T;L^p(E))$. As continuous functions on compact sets (such as the interval $[0,T]$ in this case) are bounded, does the assumption $f\in C(0,T;L^p(E))$ suffice to guarantee boundedness of the above integral or am I misunderstanding Bochner spaces? I am unsure whether or not I need additionally $f\in L^p(0,T;L^p(E))$, i.e.: $f\in C(0,T;L^p(E))\cap L^p(0,T;L^p(E))$. As I said, unsure though if this really is needed but I am not that comfortable with Bochner spaces yet.

Thanks in advance and have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f\in C([0,T]; L^p(E))$ implies $f\in L^p(0,T;L^p(E))$ for all $p$, since $T$ is finite.

However this is not enough to guarantee the existence of the integral. Also the inner ($x$) integral has to exist:
$f^{p-1}$ is in $L^\infty(0,T; L^{\frac{p}{p-1}})$, $\partial_\tau g$ belongs to $L^p(0,T;L^p(E))$. And the product is integrable. To see this, one can apply Hoelders inequality to show that the integral exists:
$$
\begin{split}
\int_{E\times(0,T)} |f^{p-1} \partial_\tau g| dx\ d\tau
&\le \int_{(0,T)} \int_E |f^{p-1} \partial_\tau g| dx\ d\tau \\
&\le \int_{(0,T)} |f(\tau)^{p-1}|_{L^{\frac{p}{p-1}}(E)} |\partial_\tau g(\tau)|_{L^p(E)} d\tau \\
&\le \int_{(0,T)} |f(\tau)|_{L^p(E)}^{p-1} |\partial_\tau g(\tau)|_{L^p(E)} d\tau \\
&\le \big\|\ |f(\tau)|_{L^p(E)}^{p-1}\ \big\|_{L^\frac{p}{p-1}(0,T)}\|\partial_\tau g(\tau)\|_{L^p(0,T;L^p(E))} \\
&\le \| f\|_{L^p(0,T,L^p(E))}^{p-1}\|\partial_\tau g(\tau)\|_{L^p(0,T;L^p(E))} < +\infty.
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Thanks @draw! 
Hm i understand that the inner integral (the $x$ inegral) has to exist of course as well but that is given by the assumptions $f\in L^p(E)$ and $g\in L^p(E)$, right?  With the first part of your answer, wouldn't we be able to have $\| f\|^{p-1}_{L^\infty}(0,T;L^p(E))$ in the last two inequalities? 

To clarify, do I need now $f\in L^p(0,T;L^p(E))$ or $f\in C(0,T;L^p(E))\cap L^p(0,T;L^p(E))$ for the above integral to exist? As far as I've understood it now,the first one suffices. Also if the first one suffices, wouldn't $g\in W^{1,1}(0,T;L^p(E))$ suffice?
Thanks again!

Comment: $f\in L^p(0,T;L^p)$ is enough, and this is implied by $f\in C([0,T],L^p)$. For $f\in C(0,T;L^p)$ the assumptions on $g$ can be reduced to $W^{1,1}$, yes. You can play with these exponents, just make sure that the Hoelder inequality works for the $x$ and $\tau$ integrals.

Comment: @draw Thanks again very much! You seem to be answering all my questions in this forum gg. Think I understood the notion of the Bochner spaces now! Before, I didn't work with continuity in time and thus had to assume much higher integrability - how strong the continuity is!

Comment: Something that still bothers me is the following: why do almost all authors in articles still assume higher integrability of the weak time derivative in case of continuity in time of sub-/supersolutions? e.g. in https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0022039683710454?token=FF2EE5E9AEAB9E6B336C8B7977E8707292E3C97F565E56E61AD642D335702FC08E05CDCC2AC6A80E77F712938663D2B5&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20230117075925 on page 149, $\psi\in W^{1,1}(0,T;L^2(k))$ would be enough as we found out above, i find that really strange to be honest... In almost every other article it's the same.

Comment: I actually want to correct myself. Until now, I couldn't find any article where they didn't assume "too much" integrability of the weak time derivative of the test functions. I find that really odd. Surely there must be a reason for that...?

Comment: Maybe this is needed somewhere else, to ensure some compactness?

Comment: Thanks again @draw. Until now I couldn't figure out if it really is needed. If I find out something, I will write it down here!